# I am trying to convert a multidimensional array to a two dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, image-processing, conv-neural-network

This is my code:

```py
segmented_characters = [cv2.imread(file) for file in glob.glob('extracted_images/*.png')]
segmented_characters = np.array(segmented_characters)

gray_segmented_characters = [cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) for image in segmented_characters]
gray_segmented_characters = np.array(gray_segmented_characters)

gray_segmented_characters = gray_segmented_characters.reshape(7684,1600)
```

and my error message is :

```
gray_segmented_characters = gray_segmented_characters.reshape(7684,1600)
```

> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 12307200 into shape (7684,1600)

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that your `reshape` dimensions `(7684, 1600)` do not cover the whole array size, which is 12307200.

A possible solution is to change your reshape dimensions to `(7692, 1600)`:

```
gray_segmented_characters = gray_segmented_characters.reshape(7692,1600)
```

Or you can crop the source image so it would fit in your required dimensions